# Clear ListView items and update from second form

Tags: c#, listview

I have  `ListView` (SessionList) in my main form (`Form1`). And I'm listing items by getting value form mysql database by calling the function `CreateSessionList()` in `Form1_Load()`.

Now I want to filter. So, I have another form (FilterForm) invoked by using the menu from main form (Form1).

`FilterForm` contains a `ComboBox` for all column header of particular table.
When I click the **Filter** button in second Form(Filter Form), I'm sending the selected data to first form(Form1), there I clear all previous items in List view and by having this new data for SELECT query to display new data in `ListView`.

What happened here is, previous list is not get cleared. It shows the count as zero. but View has the old data. No change at all.

Form1.cs  Coding

```
private void CreateSessionList()
        {

            SessionList.View = View.Details;          
            SessionList.Items.Clear();         
            MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sessiontbl", Properties.Settings.Default.DBPerfScoreConnectionString);            
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem((i+1).ToString());               
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SessionID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["InstID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Trainee"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SessDt"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelName"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add("Alarm"); 
                SessionList.Items.Add(listitem);                
            } 
        }

public void GetWhereQuery(String Sesssel, String Inssel, String Trsel, String Modsel, String Dtsel)
        {
            SessionList.Items.Clear(); //After this,item count shows 0
            SessionList.Refresh();

            String sQuery = "SELECT * FROM sessiontbl WHERE (SessionID ='"+ Sesssel+"')";
            MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter(sQuery, Properties.Settings.Default.DBPerfScoreConnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem((i + 1).ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SessionID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["InstID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Trainee"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["SessDt"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelID"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["ModelName"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add("Alarm");
                SessionList.Items.Add(listitem);
            } 

        }
```

FilterForm.cs Coding

```
private void Filterbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            

            if(sessioncombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
                 Sesssel = sessioncombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if(InstructorCombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
                 Inssel = InstructorCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if(TraineeCombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
                 Trsel = TraineeCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if(ModelCombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
                 Modsel = ModelCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if(Datecombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
                 Dtsel = Datecombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            frm = new Form1();
            frm.GetWhereQuery(Sesssel, Inssel, Trsel, Modsel, Dtsel); //Calling function of form1 to filter.
            this.Close();


        }
```

Comment: Use ConcurrentDictinary to get all data from the database.. When you want filter just fetch from dictionary..

Answer (score 0):

Just send instance of Form1 to FilterForm like

```
FilterForm form = new FilterForm();
form.Form1 = this;
form.Show();
```

In your FilterForm create property of type Form1

```
public Form1 Form { get; set;}
```

and on Filterbtn_Click call `Form1.GetWhereQuery(...);

Your changes is not applied therefore u create new instance of Form1.

Comment: Im sorry. I dont know where to use that form.Form1= this.

Comment: I got this error : Error 1 'TrainingReports.Filterform' does not contain a definition for 'Form1' and no extension method 'Form1' accepting a first argument of type 'TrainingReports.Filterform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link.I got the solution.
[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/df9359a4-deae-474a-b9db-0e0e6967d9f1/add-listview-items-from-another-form)